# How to remove extra border in WPF TextBox?

Tags: wpf, binding, textbox, border, extern

I have a problem with WPF `TextBox`. I have an `ItemsControl` with `TextBox` controls, which binds to `double` properties in some ViewModel. For these `TextBox` controls I have a `DataTrigger`

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{c:Binding 'IsCorrect'}" Value="False">
      <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="5"/>
      <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="GreenYellow"/>
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFD2D2"/>
</DataTrigger>
```

It changes `BorderThickness`, `BorderBrush` and `Background` of the `TextBox` if there was entered a wrong number.
But, if I remove all text from `TextBox`, it will not set data to binding property and change `BorderThickness` and `BorderBrush` properties, and if `DataTrigger` styles have been already set, there will be second border, which is extern for `DataTrigger's` made border.

Result Image:

[image: Screenshot of the result]

On the image `GreenYellow` border is set by `DataTrigger` and `Red` extern border set by itself.

So the QUESTION is - what is this extern border? and how to remove it?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So the QUESTION is - what is this extern border?

It's part of the default `Validation.Error` template.

> and how to remove it?!

Define a custom empty [`Validation.Error`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.validation.errortemplate?view=netframework-4.8) template:

```
<TextBox>
    <Validation.ErrorTemplate>
        <ControlTemplate />
    </Validation.ErrorTemplate>
</TextBox>
```

Or in a `Style`:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox">
    <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate />
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: You can also set it like so: `<Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" Value="{x:Null}" />`